# FlowLayout ItemsControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol, flowlayout

I need a really simple ItemsControl actually. I want all the items in the collection to be put left to right and when it's not enough space to fit the next element, it should be put on the next line.

So basically like FlowLayout in Java Swing, or the normal Icon folder view in Windows.

I can't believe this is not built in, but for some reason I can't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at these:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750564%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Specifically the WrapPanel

Edit:

The ItemsControl control has a ItemsPanel Property which you canset to use a WrapPanel:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx

Comment: My only problem here is that I have an observable collection that I need to bpund, so I actually need a ItemsControl and not a Panel. Any ideas?

Comment: Worked as a charm :) I have obviously not worked enough with WPF. Thanks for your help.