# Making the MainWindow resizeable but having the contents inside resize with it

Tags: c#, wpf, scaletransform

I need to make my mainwindow resizeable.. but it's pointless to resize it if the contents inside don't scale with it.. i googled and didnt' find much.. i did find this though:

and it doesn't work.. i have tried this:

```
<Window.RenderTransform>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.8" ScaleY="0.8" />
</Window.RenderTransform>
```

and tried this website here

```
http://inchoatethoughts.com/scaling-your-user-interface-in-a-wpf-application
```

but even trying from a blank project, it didn't work for some reason =T

EDIT: i think what makes it tricky is that i have two sets of grids.  the first grid for a mock title bar, and a second grid for the rest of the content

Comment: You can try this solution.
I think is fit for your problem too

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355999/way-to-make-wpf-dockpanel-auto-resize-based-on-its-childrens-size

Comment: hm k i'll look into this

Comment: Probbable duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988876/flowlayout-itemscontrol-in-wpf

Comment: WPF is resolution independent by default, unless you do everything wrong by using the Visual Studio designer instead of writing your XAML by hand as we all do. Post the relevant XAML and a screenshot of what you have versus what you need.

Comment: found an answer that works here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193339/tips-on-developing-resolution-independent-application/5000120#5000120

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx).

```
<Window>
    <Viewbox>
        ... your Content
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

See [Stretch Property Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for several options to scale.

Comment: was messing with this but it really doesn't do what i need